# How do I get exported types in a nice namespaces?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have these:

*src/components/Thing/State.ts:*

```
export type State = { name: string }
```

*src/components/Thing/index.ts*:

```
import { State } from './State'

const coolFunction = () => {}

export default {
  State,
  coolFunction,
}
```

because I want to say `import Thing from '../Thing'` and be able to reference `Thing.State` as well as `Thing.coolFunction`.

TypeScript is telling me that `State` is a type and not a value, but it's being used as a value. I get the concept of this error, but I don't know what to do about it. I want my related things namespaced, but this looks to be a hindrance.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable/namespace merging :

```
const coolFunction = () => {}
const e = {
    coolFunction,
}
namespace e {
    export type State = import('./State').State;

}
export default e
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you, but I it seems `namepsace` and `module` are disallowed in react native, which is what this is. At least, I'm getting that error regardless of whose fault it is.

Comment: @jyurek are you sure those are not just tslint warnings ? There is a tslint rules forbidding the use of namespaces